# Different background color either side of page

Tags: html, css, colors, background, tiling

I want to create a fixed-width layout where the background color on either side of the page is different, but with the background colours extending infinitely from either side of the page no matter how far you zoom out.

For example, I'm not looking to create a 9000x10 px image with the correct colours on either side and tiling it, as this would only work if you dont zoom out far enough to see the edge of the background image.

Is this possible?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I should have specified, the background should cover the full height of the page, not just the height of the window/viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't like the `height: 100%; position: fixed;` solution because I wanted to leave the option open of having a background image that scrolled with the page later on. (Although I didn't think of this in writing the question.) I had a play and found `min-height: 100%;` to work.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">

            body {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }

            #container {
                width: 100%;
                min-height: 100%;
                position: relative;
            }

            #left, #right {
                width: 50%;
                height: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                z-index: -1;
            }

            #left {
                left: 0;
                background-color: navy;
            }

            #right {
                right: 0;
                background-color: maroon;
            }

            #content {
                width: 512px;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0 auto;
                background-color: white;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="left"></div>
            <div id="right"></div>
            <div id="content">
                Hi<br />
                Hi<br />
                Hi<br />
                Hi<br />
                Hi<br />
                Hi<br />
                Hi<br />
                Hi<br />
                Hi<br />
                Hi<br />
                Hi<br />
                Hi<br />
                Hi<br />
                Hi<br />
                Hi<br />
                Hi<br />
                Hi<br />
                Hi<br />
                Hi<br />
                Hi<br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

For some reason it doesn't work in jsfiddle.net: http://jsfiddle.net/HktPN/ But it does in my browser.

Answer (score 7):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/EfR4a/3/) seems to work:

```
<body>
<div id="bg-right"></div>
<!-- rest of page -->
</body>
```

```
body {
  background-color: purple;
}
#bg-right {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work, but you should note that `position:fixed` isn't supported in IE6

Comment: This has an issue where you can see `1px` of the purple background where there should be yellow. (depends if the viewport width pixel count is even or odd) (testing in Chrome)

Comment: @thirtydot: That seems to be fixed now.

Comment: @Fred Nurk: Yup, it's fixed. I think I like your solution more because it only relies on one extra element.

Comment: @Fred Nurk: Neat, but unfortunately it doesn't work with our good friend IE.

Comment: I know text is a poor medium for sarcasm, but "good friend" almost made me snort coffee.

Answer (score 3):

This works in IE7+ with both little and lots of content:

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/daLpj/) (lots of content)
[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/daLpj/1/) (little content)

HTML:

```
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="container"></div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; 
}
body {
    background: #ccc
}
#left, #right {
    position: fixed;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0
}
#left {
    background: #ccc;
    left: 0
}
#right {
    background: #999;
    right: 0
}
#container {
    background: #fff;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How's this for you? http://jsfiddle.net/PNYVe/

Comment: if the content is large, and the vertical scroll appears, the background will not stretch to the end. example: http://jsfiddle.net/dan86/PNYVe/2/

Comment: Ah, what Dan said. I need that too. :/

Comment: Just change from `absolute` to `fixed`. It seems to work that way. http://jsfiddle.net/JzTdF/

Answer (score 0):

using Matt example, just adding a container solves it :
http://jsfiddle.net/PNYVe/3/

Comment: This solves the issue of having too much content. But try deleting some of the contents, the background will shrink to the size of the content, and won't fill the whole page xD